# Form submission issues with authentication

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

The following [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP6zX.jpg) provides background for this question

I am posting form data to a Flask URL. The HTML form looks like so.

```html
{% extends "AdminMaster.html" %} {% block title %}Create New Application{% endblock %} {% block page %}Create New Application{% endblock %} {% block head %} {{ super() }} {% endblock %} {% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Create a new Application</h1>
  </div>
  <form action="/xxxx/xdf">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txtApplicationName">Application Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtApplicationName" placeholder="Application Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txtApplicationCategoryName">Application Category Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtApplicationCategoryName" placeholder="Application Category">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      Add New Category
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have the following Flask route to handle the post.

```
@admin_routes.route('/xxxx/xdf', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@authenticate_admin
def create_new_application():
    app_name = request.args[0]
    return redirect('/xxxx')
```

The problem is everytime I make a post I get the 400 Bad Request. I am not sure why ?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the traceback that is leading to the bad request?

Comment: Just added the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.args` is a `MultiDict`. It is not a sequence. You access its elements with keys, not indexes.

```
request.args['some_name']
```

Here `'some_name'` matches the name attribute of a form element.

```
<input type="text" name="some_name">
```

Without providing the name attribute, the browser won't include the field in the http GET or POST request.

```
      <input type="text" name="????" class="form-control" id="txtApplicationCategoryName" placeholder="Application Category">
```

Comment: Thanks so the form is submitting, but I am still getting the 400

Comment: I have just added the stack trace to the question. Thanks

Comment: That's logging information, not the traceback. Please share the full traceback as well as line 812 from `module.py`.